# Google Maps API: Static Map returns Error and no map is available

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I opened an account on Google, and I went to https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager to create a Key to use Google Maps static API.

I used that Key, on-site pages as well as on AMP pages but while on AMP it works fine, on the normal HTML Page, Google's API returns an error.

Investigating it with Developer Tool of Chrome, it returns MissingKeyMapError which it has no sense because the same key is running on the AMP version of the site.

I debug the webpage (generated by PHP) and I saw: all Geo-data, are correctly retrieved from Google, by CURL etc ...

Just the Javascript of Google doesn't return the map ...

I attach a screenshot of the error code from JS Console of Chrome:[image]

Here below the variable contanining my Key (written in setup.php file)

$key_gigs = "_____________MYKEY______________";

here CLASS I use for AMP as well as for normal HTML pages:

```
<?php
class geo {

    public function CoOrdinates($address_) {

    global $key_gigs; // Setup.php
    //echo $address_; echo $key_gigs; exit; // debug purpose
    $curl_ = curl_init();
    $url_map = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address_&sensor=false&key=$key_gigs";
    curl_setopt($curl_, CURLOPT_URL, $url_map);
    curl_setopt($curl_, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl_);
    curl_close($curl_);

    $data = json_decode($curlData, true);
    //print_r($data);   exit; // debug purpose
    $ret_ = [
        'city' => $data["results"][0]["address_components"][2]["long_name"],
        'country' => $data["results"][0]["address_components"][5]["long_name"],
        'iso' => strtolower($data["results"][0]["address_components"][5]["short_name"]),

        'lat' => $data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],
        'lon' => $data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"],

        'time-zone' => $this->TimeZone($data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],$data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]),
    ];
    //print_r($ret_); exit; // debug purpose
    return $ret_ ;
    }

    public function TimeZone($lat_,$lon_) {
        //echo $lat_." ".$lon_; exit;

        $query_json = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location={$lat_},{$lon_}&timestamp=0&sensor=false";
        $json_timezone = file_get_contents($query_json);
        $data_time_zone = json_decode($json_timezone, true);
        return $time_zone = $data_time_zone["timeZoneId"];
    }
}
?>
```

Here the interested part of the PHP code that generates the page (it's located into the pre-processor of the page)

```
$address = add_plus($Address.", ".$Number.",".$Code."+".$City.",".$Country);

// Creates and manages object from Class geo();
$geo = new geo();
$coordinates = $geo->CoOrdinates($address);
$city = $coordinates['city'];
$country = $coordinates['country'];
$iso = $coordinates['iso'];
$lat = $coordinates['lat'];
$lon = $coordinates['lon'];
$time_zone = $coordinates['time-zone'];
// GEO Debug
//echo $city." ".$country." ".$iso." ".$lat." ".$lon." ".$time_zone; exit;
```

And here the META tag for the Google JS. The following code lines, are located into the page itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Here the visualization code. Variables like $venue, etc, are generated by the pre-processor of the page, and data, taken from dB

```
    <!-- Map style="width: 60vw; height: 33.8vw;" -->
    <section>
            <h2 class="h_special"><? echo $Name; ?> - EVENTO</h2>
            <div id="gmap" style=""></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        var myLatLng = {lat: <? echo $lat; ?>, lng: <? echo $lon; ?>};
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: <? echo $zoom; ?>,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $lat; ?>, <? echo $lon; ?>),
            // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng, map: map, title: '<? echo $venue; ?>'});
            </script>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Javascript API error code documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error) as well your screenshot shows, MissingKeyMapError occurs because you are missing an API key in your Javascript API load URL and has nothing to do with the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

You need to add an API key to that URL, as the [Getting Started documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#step-2-add-the-api-key-to-your-application) says. You also [do not need the sensor parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Preston , In another website, I used exactly the same code, and I didn't put the key right there where you did suggest. But it works very well.

Thus I still don't understand why it doesn't work on the same code, just another domain, another user . Set up is the same for both website.

Working page (without the key you suggested) https://www.liciafox.net/venues/io-non-ti-lascero-mai

Same code here, but not working:

https://www.barbaravagnini.it/venues/barbara-e-band

That's why I opened this thread. ... Right?

Comment: On Jun 22, 2016, the Javascript API was required to use an API key due to sweeping [Standard Plan changes](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update). Any domains that were already using the JS API before that date could continue to work without an API key. But any domains created after that date are required to use a key. If that is a new domain, you will need to add an API key.

Comment: Thank you so much @Preston for the clarification. Indeed I now put the key and it works

Comment: Glad to hear! Happy to help